# AWR PA Output Power Simulation - Credible?

Tags: rf, simulation, microwave, power-amplifier

I'm working with the [SKY65111-348LF](http://www.skyworksinc.com/uploads/documents/200428E.pdf) power amplifier from Skyworks and wanted to obtain some idea of its performance using AWR Microwave Office. I'm not sure if my process is correct and wanted to have it verified by someone with more design experience.

Starting out, I created a system block diagram that consists of the amplifier with its corresponding parameters and a low-pass filter (LPF) to mitigate harmonics. It is worth noting the LPF block references an S2P file.

[image: System Block Diagram]

Based on the datasheet parameters given, I entered what was available in the amplifier "Basic Settings":

[image]

Tuning the model, I found that -0.5 dBm input power yielded +30 dBm output, which is my desired value. The following graphs were obtained:

[image]
[image]

I am wondering if the PA parameters - on page 3 of the datasheet - were entered correctly and if the resulting output plots can be trusted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, All simulations are wrong. Some of them are useful.

You've got a behavioral model that claims a P1dB of 29.5 dBm, and a PSat of 33 dBm. The amplifier has 40 dB of gain, and you're putting in -0.5 dBm. Now, a perfectly linear PA would put our +39.5 dBm minus whatever the Low pass filter losses are. You're driving that amp pretty far into compression, so it really depends on how ADS has modeled compression. I'd suspect that the output directly out of the PA is +33 dBm, and that low pass filter is pretty lossy. Figure out what the low pass filter losses are, and you could figure it out

I suspect you're in the ballpark.